# Optimize gas consumption when writing to store and memory

Tags: solidity

I have array of `uint`s in contract's storage, now I want to sort it. Quicksort involves swap two array elements if necessary. But as I understand it would be 2 writes to storage. I am thinking that it would be better to copy storage array to memory and operates on memory's one and then - store it back.

My questions is:

1. Am I right that each `uint` swapping in array cause 2 storage write calls?
2. Does it makes sense to copy that array to memory and when sorted - store back?

Comment: For #1: You could technically devise an algorithm that will do one storage-write operation per entry (by copying the entry that you're about to overwrite into a local variable, at each iteration). So the answer to this question depends on your implementation. For #2: Depends on the size of the array. The answer probably changes from 'no' to 'yes' at a specific point (e.g., 'no' if the array is 20 entries or less, 'yes' otherwise). It would probably be advisable to profile the two methods (using `estimateGas`) and then decide which one is better.

Comment: Instead of sorting did you try keeping the data always sorted using a heap? In theory sound better instead of paying the full price at once you distribute it over several transactions.

Comment: @Ismael do you suggest to user doulbe-linked list instead of array? Solidity does not allow to insert items into the middle of array.

Comment: @Ismael insert something into the array with 10k elements cause too much gas to pay for users.

Comment: A double linked list doesn't sound great, you will have to reserve space for the forward and backward "pointers". Depending on the size of you data if each item is bigger than 32 bytes a better idea is to have an index and sort that instead (even you can use 4 or 8 bytes por item). My suggestion as to use a [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) but I think even 10k entries is a bit too much. It might be it is too many entries for sorting with the current gas limit, either sort offline or split the sorting into several transactions.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for great idea, it is already in past - I'd have array for structs and separate array for indices. Unfortunately I faced the same problem that - sort 10k of uints with check sort member in mapping/array of items is too expensive - more then 200 items causes `out of gas` with gas limit about 4kk.

Comment: @Ismael FYI: simple heap implementation on the top of array cause about 3kk gas for inserting 50 elements.